# Passsing arrays arguments in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup

I'm starting to work with python again after 8 years. I'm trying to do program with `BeautifulSoup` and a array argument. I pass the array argument `medios` to the `url` functions `count_words`, but it doesn't work. Is there a way fix it or to search a word in multiple websites using `BeautifulSoup`?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    words = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and the_word in text)
 #   print(words)
    return len(words)

def main():
    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    medios = {
        'Los Angeles Times': ['http://www.latimes.com/'],
        'New York Times' : ['http://www.nytimes.com/'
    ] }

    word = 'Trump'
    #count = count_words(url, word)
    cuenta = count_words(medios, word)
   # print('\n El Sitio: {}\n Contiene {} occurrencias de la palabra: {}'.format(url, count, word))
    print('\n La palabra: {} aparece {} occurrencias en el New York Times'.format(word, cuenta))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems here

1. `medios` is a `dict`. Hence, you will have to loop through the keys and values to send it to the method as the method only accepts url string.
2. BeautifulSoup `find` method needs a tag name for it to search else it will return `None`. If you want to count the number of occurrences of the word, then use `count` on the string.
3. You have to send User-Agent in the requests code else you will get `403` or `301`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.text.lower().count(the_word)

def main():
    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    medios = {
        'Los Angeles Times': ['http://www.latimes.com/'],
        'New York Times' : ['http://www.nytimes.com/']
    }

    word = 'trump'
    
    for web_name, urls in medios.items():
        for url in urls:
            cuenta = count_words(url, word)
            print('La palabra: {} aparece {} occurrencias en el {}'.format(word, cuenta, web_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
La palabra: trump aparece 47 occurrencias en el Los Angeles Times
La palabra: trump aparece 194 occurrencias en el New York Times
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a dictionary to `count_words()`.  You need to send the urls in a loop, or else loop thru the dictionary in `count_words()`.

Perhaps you meant:

```
cuenta = count_words(url, word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to the following:

```py
cuenta = 0
for key in medios:
    for url in medios[key]:
        cuenta += count_words(url, word)
```

Basically you should pass the `url` not a dict, and I am assuming you want to count all the words in all elements in `medios`.